# cannot insert data into the 4th table

Tags: oracle, insert, null, constraints

I used the following script to create 4 test tables: dept1, dept2, dept3, and dept4. The code is exactly the same for each table. All tables are created successfully but the insert into statements only worked for the first three tables. After dropping all tables and purge the recyclebin, I moved Create Table dept4 and the following insert into statements to the top of the code. Then the insert into statement does not work for Dept3. Basically, I can only insert data into the first three tables in the script and not able to insert data into the 4th table on the script.

The error message is the following:
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 
ORA-30667: cannot drop NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column 
00604. 00000 - "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"

This happened after some users created identity columns in Oracle 12.1 database. Some users used: 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
Other users used: 
GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY

Code used:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT1 (
DEPT1NO              NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
DNAME               VARCHAR2(14),
LOC                 VARCHAR2(13),
CONSTRAINT DEPT1_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (DEPT1NO));
INSERT INTO DEPT1 VALUES (10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO DEPT1 VALUES (20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS');
INSERT INTO DEPT1 VALUES (30,'SALES','CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO DEPT1 VALUES (40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON');



CREATE TABLE DEPT2 (
DEPT2NO              NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
DNAME               VARCHAR2(14),
LOC                 VARCHAR2(13),
CONSTRAINT DEPT2_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (DEPT2NO));
INSERT INTO DEPT2 VALUES (10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO DEPT2 VALUES (20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS');
INSERT INTO DEPT2 VALUES (30,'SALES','CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO DEPT2 VALUES (40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON');

CREATE TABLE DEPT3 (
DEPT3NO              NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
DNAME               VARCHAR2(14),
LOC                 VARCHAR2(13),
CONSTRAINT DEPT3_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (DEPT3NO));
INSERT INTO DEPT3 VALUES (10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO DEPT3 VALUES (20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS');
INSERT INTO DEPT3 VALUES (30,'SALES','CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO DEPT3 VALUES (40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON');

CREATE TABLE DEPT4 (
DEPT4NO              NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
DNAME               VARCHAR2(14),
LOC                 VARCHAR2(13),
CONSTRAINT DEPT4_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (DEPT4NO));
INSERT INTO DEPT4 VALUES (10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO DEPT4 VALUES (20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS');
INSERT INTO DEPT4 VALUES (30,'SALES','CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO DEPT4 VALUES (40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON');
```

Comment: "Some users used: .." So you are not showing all the details.